# Javascript Input Set Value with Recalculation

Tags: javascript, function, getelementbyid

I am trying to develop a java web application. I want to calculate an inputtext value from other inputs and based on checkbox. The code is below. I can set inputtext ("mvkpayinput") value with "mvkhsp" value. The code work till **last** **if condition**. However, I need one more condition, if the input "textndhmvk" is "true". The final value of "mvkpayinput" input should be mvkhsp - *other value*. If  textndhmvk is not true function is working, but if textndhmvk is **true**, then the result is **"Nan"**

The problem is exactly "Number(mvkhsp)" part in the last line. If I change Number() with ParseInt() it calculates but the calculation is not correct, I also tried Math..()etc. But I could not figure out why the "Number(mvkhsp)" does not work. This is just one sample, I need to figure out how I can recalculate and set value to an inputtext.

```
<script>
    function myFunctionPycalc() {

    var textsap = document.getElementById("posap").value;
    var texttap = document.getElementById("potap").value;
    var textndhm = document.getElementById("pondhm").value;
    var textnakitmvk = document.getElementById("ponakitmvk").value;

        if (checkBox1.checked) {
         mvkhsp =(Number(textsap) + Number(texttap)).toLocaleString('tr-TR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
         }else {
          mvkhsp =(Number(textsap)).toLocaleString('tr-TR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
         }

    document.getElementById("mvkpayinput").value = mvkhsp;


     if (textndhmvk=="true") {
      document.getElementById("mvkpayinput").value = (Number(mvkhsp) - Number(textnakitmvk)).toLocaleString('tr-TR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different languages. Please don't tag Java when asking about JavaScript (and vice-versa)

Comment: Please create a [mre] using the `<>` button to add a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake.

Because I use toLocaleString('tr-TR'), the value assigned cannot be read again correctly as number, after I remove the toLocaleString('tr-TR') above and changed the code as below, the code works well now.

```
>  if (textndhmvk=="true") {
>       document.getElementById("mvkpayinput").value = (Number(mvkhsp) - Number(textnakitmvk)).toLocaleString('tr-TR', {minimumFractionDigits:
> 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
>      } else {  document.getElementById("mvkpayinput").value = (mvkhsp).toLocaleString('tr-TR', {minimumFractionDigits:
> 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}); }
```